# Close text file when I already use Workbooks.OpenText to open it

Tags: excel, vba

i'm new in this forum and I would like to share my wisdom and you convey me yours.

I have enough experience with Excel Macros but this problem I couldn't find a solution.

I open a text file with Workbooks.OpenText to work in Excel.

`Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=myfile, DataType:=xlDelimited, Origin:=xlWindows, Other:=True, OtherChar:=","`

But when I will close it, I can't. I try with the next instructions:

- Workbooks(myfile).Close
- ActiveWorkbook.Close

`myfile = "path\file.txt"`

When i use this instructions, Excel says that i cant use it. I only need to take some information of this text files and close it without save.

Can anybody help me with these?

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Close` works for me.

Comment: BTW are you sure the focus is not changing from the workbook after opening it?

Comment: Works if you have this file in focus, but if you paste the information in another workbook, u cant back again to the text file with "Windows(myfile).Activate".

Anyway thanks for your comment.

Comment: One you have `myfile = GetFilenameFromPath(myfile)` as in my code thn you can use `Windows(myfile).Activate` as well :)

Comment: Ye, I use Windows(myfile).Activate and works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This also works for me

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim myfile As String

    myfile = "C:\Delete Me.txt"

    Workbooks.OpenText fileName:=myfile, _
                       DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                       Origin:=xlWindows, _
                       Other:=True, _
                       OtherChar:=","


    myfile = GetFilenameFromPath(myfile)

    Workbooks(myfile).Close
End Sub

Public Function GetFilenameFromPath(ByVal strPath As String) As String
    If Right$(strPath, 1) <> "\" And Len(strPath) > 0 Then
        GetFilenameFromPath = _
        GetFilenameFromPath(Left$(strPath, Len(strPath) - 1)) + Right$(strPath, 1)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Great mate!

This function works perfect.

Thanks you very much!